# Threading error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_initialized'

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I'm trying to learn about threading on Python 3.
I made an example code:

```
import time 
import threading

def myfunction(string,sleeptime,lock,*args):
  count = 0
  while count < 2:
    #entering critical section
    lock.acquire()
    print(string, " Now sleeping after Lock acquired for ",sleeptime)
    time.sleep(sleeptime)
    print(string, " Now releasing lock and sleeping again.\n",time.ctime(time.time()))
    lock.release()
    #exiting critical section
    time.sleep(sleeptime)
    count+=1
    #threading.Thread.daemon=True

if __name__!="__main__":
  lock = threading.Lock()
  try:
    threading.Thread.start(myfunction("Thread Nº 1",2,lock))
    threading.Thread.start(myfunction("Thread Nº 2",2,lock))
  except:
    raise

  while 1:pass
```

It works in part. When it reaches the `while<2 loop`, it returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 22, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_initialized'
```

And never executes the second thread call.

What can I do to correct this?

Thank you all!

Comment: `__name__ != "__main__"` doesn't look correct at all. Usually the condition is reversed...

Comment: .. i.e. `__name__ == '__main__'`

Comment: Thank you @antti-haapala, but I'm running a web Python interpreter... so the __name__ = builtins, not main.... I've already removed this verification.

Comment: ah, that's bad :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the `Thread` completely incorrectly. First of all, you're not calling the *`Thread`* constructor (i.e. your code *must* have `threading.Thread(<something>)` to create new `Thread` instances). Secondly, you're calling the `myfunction` with arguments in the *main* thread, not in a new thread. Third, the return value of that function (the implicit `None`) is passed as the implicit `self` argument to the unbound `Thread.start` method!

The proper way to do it would be

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=myfunction, args=("Thread Nº 1", 2, lock))
t1.start()
```

Likewise for `t2`. 
Additionally, if you do it like this, you will retain references to the `Thread` objects, and you can replace the `while 1: pass` with

```
t1.join()
t2.join()
print("Both threads exited, exiting.")
```

Or equally:

```
for t in [t1, t2]:
    t.join()
print("Both threads exited, exiting.")
```

With these modifications, the program will output

```
Thread Nº 1  Now sleeping after Lock acquired for  2
Thread Nº 1  Now releasing lock and sleeping again.
 Mon Jun 26 17:42:32 2017
Thread Nº 2  Now sleeping after Lock acquired for  2
Thread Nº 2  Now releasing lock and sleeping again.
 Mon Jun 26 17:42:34 2017
Thread Nº 1  Now sleeping after Lock acquired for  2
Thread Nº 1  Now releasing lock and sleeping again.
 Mon Jun 26 17:42:36 2017
Thread Nº 2  Now sleeping after Lock acquired for  2
Thread Nº 2  Now releasing lock and sleeping again.
 Mon Jun 26 17:42:38 2017
Both threads exited, exiting.
```

Comment: You may also want to mention using `t1.join()` rather than `while 1: pass`

Comment: Ah, sorry, jumped the gun. Good answer.

Comment: I made those changes, but now the "myfunction" funcition doesn't run... It jumps to the "Both threads exited, exiting." message.
`if __name__!="__main__":
  lock = threading.Lock()
  t1 = threading.Thread(target="myfunction",args=("Thread Nº 1",2,lock))
  t2 = threading.Thread(target="myfunction",args=("Thread Nº 2",3,lock))
  t1.start()
  t2.start()
  t1.join()
  t2.join()
  print("All threads exited, exiting...")`

Comment: I found my error! 
It is not `target="myfunction"` but `target=myfunction`.
Thanks a lot, @Antti-Haapala!